# Max input current of DC DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this kind of question(mine seems practical as opposed to academic) but here it goes.

The embedded board I am using(Jetson TX1) can be powered using:

- 4S LiPO(4 cell / 14.8V nominal / 16.8V charged) with 1-2A (or 15W) of
  continuous current
      or
- 3S LiPO (11.1V nominal / 12.6 charged / 9V    discharged) with 1-2A
  (or 15W) of continuous current

(from https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/914529/jetson-tx1/battery-for-jetson-tx1/1)

I'm trying to mount Jetson TX1 on my quadrocopter which has XT30/XT60 ports with the following spec:

- Output Voltage: 20 - 26.1 V
- Max Continuous Output Current: 10 A

(from http://wiki.dji.com/en/index.php/Matrice_100-Reserved_Ports_Description)

Now I'm trying to buy a DC-DC step down converter and I'm currently looking at *DROK 200143 DC-DC Buck Converter 3.5-30V to 0.8-29V 10A Step-down Volt Adjustable Output Regulator Module Power Supply* which has

- 3.5-30V input
- 0.8-29V output output
- 10A Max output current

My concern is the input current. The output current only needs to be 2A but it should take 10A input current.

Is the max input current same as the max output current?

Comment: Just because your source can deliver 10A it doesn't mean your regulator has to draw 10A.  If you use the regulator to drop the voltage, then it will draw less current than it puts out.  So, for a 2A output it will draw a little less than 2A from the battery.  You must match the input voltage range, but current is different.

Comment: 10A max current is the current it can support on that rail. Based on Load actual current varies. Use following eqn Input power * efficiency = Output power to calculate input current. It doesn't require to handle 10A input current, Based on load requirement current varies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means this converter is capable of giving you max 10A, not that it will use all 10A from the power source, as @JRE stated.
So you can use this DC-DC converter. Moreover, you will only need 2A max, so you maybe can find a smaller or cheaper DC-DC converter.

Comment: Ah I see. I found a better one here(https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00JUFJ1GA/ref=twister_B0179OMIR2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1). Another quick question: do you by any chance know how i can connect XT30 to this converter, and connect the converter to a DC barrel?

Comment: will the banana plugs(found here https://www.amazon.com/HobbyKing-charge-banana-plugs-Booole/dp/B01EE0VEJC/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1481015059&sr=8-6&keywords=xt30) fit the input holes on the converter? and can i use this (https://www.amazon.com/SIM-NAT-Pigtails-Security-Application/dp/B01GPL8MVG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1481016313&sr=8-1&keywords=dc+barrel) for the output?

Comment: The converter looks fine, but if you're planning to mount it in a quadcopter, you better find the smallest and lightest one (are you sure you need the display?). About the XT30 connectors; I can't help you, I've never used them.

Comment: Good point. I'll find a smaller one. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Only a small advice: I would search for a slightly bigger converter, at least 10% more power (say >2.2A) to be sure.

Comment: hmm but my board can only handle between 1-2A according to the forum(link is in the original post). Is it okay to supply more than 2A?

Comment: As we tried to say before, you are not "pushing" current from the converter to the device, it's the device that is "pulling" the current from the converter. It's not that your board "can handle 1-2A"; it's that your board *will draw up to 2A*. So, don't worry, you're not going to "overdrive" it.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with another question but apparently the board's peak current is 7.5A, so I chose this(https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B017SLMVXM/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=AFHAE9RJVUMB) since it can output 10A. Question: will i be able to supply two different boards with one dc-dc converter even though it has only one pair of output pins? Do i need to hook it up to a breadboard to power two devices?

Comment: Maybe, but it will probably fail if both boards draw 7.5A (14A total!) at the same time.